# Зависает сайт после авторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

После авторизации зависает сайт, точнее уходит в бесконечную загрузку. При этом, если проходить все шаги через точки остановки, то сайт нормально перекидывает на главную страницу. Также, если принудительно перейти на главную страницу, то нормально переходит с уже авторизованным пользователем.
Шаблон авторизации стандартный:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
      if (user != null)
      {
          await SignInAsync(user, true);
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
      else
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователя с таким логином и паролем нет");
      }
   }
   return View(model);
}

private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
   AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
   AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}

private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
   get
   {
      return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
   }
}
```

Comment: Похоже на проблемы асинхронности, но явно в вашем коде ненормального ничего не вижу. Что будет если во время "зависшей" загрузки поставить отладчик на паузу, на каком методе он остановится? Можно посмотреть стек вызовов, возможно deadlock, но надо понять, чем вызван. Так же, если поставить брейпоинт на `RedirectToAction`, дойдет ли до него?

Comment: Да, доходит полностью. Уже упоминал, что если с самого начала и до конца пройтись отладкой по коду, то загрузка проходит нормально и, как положено, редиректит на главную страницу.
Upd: Я вообще не понимаю, что произошло, но сегодня я снова запустил проект и всё нормально заработало. Необъяснимо.